# How to include pending orders into Magento 2 'Order Report' table 'sales_order_aggregated_created'?

Tags: orders, order-status, reports, magento2.3.5-p1, place-order

I have to run 'pending' order status report, as checked by default Magento 2 doesn't allowed to run pending reports as this doesn't make any sense.

Magento 2 ignoring to list pending order status into multiselect field shown in the below attachment from the file :-

```
vendor/magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form.php
```

[image]

After commenting the code, I am able to list pending order status into multiselect field

[image]

[image]

But after selecting 'pending' order status and then click on 'Show Report', empty report is getting in the list which is wrong.

Debug further and found that, table **'sales_order_aggregated_created'** is responsible to display report and this table doesn't include pending records that's why I am getting empty records for pending order status.

**So can anyone please let me know which file is responsible for inserting records into table 'sales_order_aggregated_created' ?** and the record is inserting after placing order OR changing the status of the order from backend  ?

I tried to find the file and find following file related with my search :-

```
magento\module-reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection.php
magento\module-sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Createdat.php
```

& removed pending restriction from both above file and place one 'COD' order but doesn't find any entry of this pending record into table **'sales_order_aggregated_created'**.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the solution:-**

To display 'pending' status into multiselect field(`Magento Admin->Reports->Sales->Orders->Order Status->Specified->Multiselect)`:-

**app\code\MyNamespace\Sales\etc\adminhtml\di.xml :-**

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form\Order" type="MyNamespace\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Rewrite\Report\Filter\FormExtended" />
```

**Note :-** Here instead of overriding method _prepareForm() of the class :-

```
magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form.php
```

**i am overriding class :-**

```
Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Rewrite\Report\Filter\Form\Order
```

As we can't override class :-

`magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form.php` method _prepareForm()  as this is also using as parent for some other classes.

Throgh overriding, I have removed condition  if (false === strpos($code, 'pending')) and doing this first of all I have removed original field 'order_statuses' and then adding new throgh the overrided file:-
`MyNamespace\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Rewrite\Report\Filter\FormExtended` including pending status.

**app\code\MyNamespace\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Rewrite\Report\Filter\FormExtended.php:-**

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Rewrite\Report\Filter;

use \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form\Order;
use \MyNamespace\Sales\Helper\PendingReportConfig;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ConfigFactory;

class FormExtended extends Order
{
    /**
     * Order config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ConfigFactory
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var PendingReportConfig
     */
    protected $pendingReportConfig;

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    protected $requestParams;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param ConfigFactory $orderConfig
     * @param pendingReportConfig $pendingReportConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        ConfigFactory $orderConfig,
        PendingReportConfig $pendingReportConfig,
        Http $requestParams,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->pendingReportConfig = $pendingReportConfig;
        $this->requestParams = $requestParams;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $orderConfig, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $params = $this->requestParams->getParams();

        $isPendingReportEnabled = $this->pendingReportConfig->isPendingReportEnabled($params);

        parent::_prepareForm();

        if ($isPendingReportEnabled) {
            $fieldset = $this->getForm()->getElement('base_fieldset');

            $fieldset->removeField('order_statuses');

            $statuses = $this->_orderConfig->create()->getStatuses();

            $values = [];
            foreach ($statuses as $code => $label) {
                $values[] = ['label' => __($label), 'value' => $code];
            }


            $fieldset->addField(
                'order_statuses',
                'multiselect',
                [
                    'name' => 'order_statuses',
                    'label' => '',
                    'values' => $values,
                    'display' => 'none'
                ],
                'show_order_statuses'
            );

            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

On refreshing Order Statistics `(Magento Admin->Reports->Statistics->Refresh Statistics)`, order records  updated into the table `'sales_order_aggregated_created'` and `'sales_order_aggregated_updated'` so to update pending records here overrided core classes `Createdat` and `Updatedat` under:-

**app\code\MyNamespace\Sales\etc\adminhtml\di.xml :-**

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Createdat" type="MyNamespace\Sales\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Createdat" /> 

<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Updatedat" type="MyNamespace\Sales\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Updatedat" />
```

**MyNamespace\Sales\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Createdat.php:-**

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Sales\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Report\Order;

use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Createdat as SalesCreatedat;

class Createdat extends SalesCreatedat
{
    protected function _aggregateByField($aggregationField, $from, $to)
    {

        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            if ($from !== null || $to !== null) {
                $subSelect = $this->_getTableDateRangeSelect(
                    $this->getTable('sales_order'),
                    $aggregationField,
                    $aggregationField,
                    $from,
                    $to
                );
            } else {
                $subSelect = null;
            }
            $this->_clearTableByDateRange($this->getMainTable(), $from, $to, $subSelect);

            $periodExpr = $connection->getDatePartSql(
                $this->getStoreTZOffsetQuery(
                    ['o' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
                    'o.' . $aggregationField,
                    $from,
                    $to
                )
            );
            // Columns list
            $columns = [
                'period' => $periodExpr,
                'store_id' => 'o.store_id',
                'order_status' => 'o.status',
                'orders_count' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(o.entity_id)'),
                'total_qty_ordered' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.total_qty_ordered)'),
                'total_qty_invoiced' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.total_qty_invoiced)'),
                'total_income_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_grand_total', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_canceled', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_revenue_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_profit_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s - %s - %s - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_paid', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced_cost', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_invoiced_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_canceled_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_canceled', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_paid_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_paid', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_refunded_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_tax_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_amount', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_canceled', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_tax_amount_actual' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s -%s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_shipping_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_amount', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_canceled', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_shipping_amount_actual' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_discount_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((ABS(%s) - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_amount', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_canceled', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_discount_amount_actual' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf(
                        'SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_invoiced', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_refunded', 0),
                        $connection->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
            ];

            $select = $connection->select();
            $selectOrderItem = $connection->select();

            $qtyCanceledExpr = $connection->getIfNullSql('qty_canceled', 0);
            $cols = [
                'order_id' => 'order_id',
                'total_qty_ordered' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(qty_ordered - {$qtyCanceledExpr})"),
                'total_qty_invoiced' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(qty_invoiced)'),
            ];
            $selectOrderItem->from(
                $this->getTable('sales_order_item'),
                $cols
            )->where(
                'parent_item_id IS NULL'
            )->group(
                'order_id'
            );

            $select->from(
                ['o' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
                $columns
            )->join(
                ['oi' => $selectOrderItem],
                'oi.order_id = o.entity_id',
                []
            );

            if ($subSelect !== null) {
                $select->having($this->_makeConditionFromDateRangeSelect($subSelect, 'period'));
            }

            $select->group([$periodExpr, 'o.store_id', 'o.status']);

            $connection->query($select->insertFromSelect($this->getMainTable(), array_keys($columns)));

            // setup all columns to select SUM() except period, store_id and order_status
            foreach ($columns as $k => $v) {
                $columns[$k] = new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(' . $k . ')');
            }
            $columns['period'] = 'period';
            $columns['store_id'] = new \Zend_Db_Expr(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
            $columns['order_status'] = 'order_status';

            $select->reset();
            $select->from($this->getMainTable(), $columns)->where('store_id <> 0');

            if ($subSelect !== null) {
                $select->where($this->_makeConditionFromDateRangeSelect($subSelect, 'period'));
            }

            $select->group(['period', 'order_status']);
            $connection->query($select->insertFromSelect($this->getMainTable(), array_keys($columns)));
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $connection->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**MyNamespace\Sales\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Updatedat.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Sales\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Report\Order;

class Updatedat extends Createdat
{
    public function aggregate($from = null, $to = null)
    {
        return $this->_aggregateByField('updated_at', $from, $to);
    }
}
```

**Also given configuration so that we can disabled this feature whenever required :-**

**code\MyNamespace\Sales\etc\adminhtml\system.xml**

```
 <section id="reports" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2000" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
             <group id="options" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="enable_pending_report" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enable Pending Reports</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                        <comment>If disabled, pending reports can't be genrated</comment>
                </field>
             </group>
        </section>
```

**code\MyNamespace\Sales\Helper\PendingReportConfig.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Sales\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Class PendingReportConfig
 * @package MyNamespace\Sales\Helper
 */
class PendingReportConfig extends AbstractHelper
{
    const PENDING_REPORTS = 'reports/options/enable_pending_report';
    const WEBSITE = 'website';
    const STORE = 'store';
    const GROUP = 'group';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }


    public function getPendingReportConfigVal($scope = null, $scopeId = null)
    {
        switch ($scope) {
            case self::WEBSITE:
                $storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE;
                break;
            case self::STORE:
                $storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
                break;
            case self::GROUP:
                $storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_GROUP;
                break;
        }
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PENDING_REPORTS, $storeScope, $scopeId);
    }

    public function isPendingReportEnabled($params)
    {
        $pendingReportEnabled = false;
        $pendingReportEnabledGlobally = false;

        if (isset($params['website'])) {
            $pendingReportEnabled = $this->getPendingReportConfigVal(self::WEBSITE, $params['website']);
        } else if (isset($params['store_ids'])) {
            $pendingReportEnabled = $this->getPendingReportConfigVal(self::STORE, $params['store_ids']);
        } else if (isset($params['group'])) {
            $pendingReportEnabled = $this->getPendingReportConfigVal(self::GROUP, $params['group']);
        } else {
            $pendingReportEnabledGlobally = $this->isPendingReportEnabledGlobally();
        }

        if (
            (isset($params['website']) && $pendingReportEnabled) ||
            (isset($params['store_ids']) && $pendingReportEnabled) ||
            (isset($params['group']) && $pendingReportEnabled) ||
            $pendingReportEnabledGlobally

        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function isPendingReportEnabledGlobally()
    {
        $WEBSITE_PENDING_REPORTS_ENABLED = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PENDING_REPORTS, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
        $STORE_PENDING_REPORTS_ENABLED = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PENDING_REPORTS, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $GROUP_PENDING_REPORTS_ENABLED = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PENDING_REPORTS, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_GROUP);
        if (
            ($WEBSITE_PENDING_REPORTS_ENABLED) ||
            ($STORE_PENDING_REPORTS_ENABLED) ||
            ($GROUP_PENDING_REPORTS_ENABLED)

        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```